# Merge two different meshes with two different armatures armatures, and their respective animations

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to make two different armatures with different animations come together as one mesh and one animation.

Sadly, nothing seems to be working, I've looked for answers online and tried quite a bit myself.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> just deforms one of the meshes and won't animate

Parenting does the same thing when parenting animations

Any ideas?

Comment: Merging the two Meshes, then the two Armatures, should work. Just make sure each bone/vertex group has a unique name before merging (otherwise, one bone will be automatically renamed to avoid duplicate, but the two vertex groups will be merged together)

Comment: sadly, it doesnt exactly. not only do the animations match up like they used to when they were'nt merged, but the other skeleton that I merged with this one isn't moving at all.  
https://gyazo.com/8a1bbdacb1e26da05bb2fdea048deb2b

Comment: Indeed, merging the armatures keeps only the keys of the Active one. I managed to keep them by : copying all the keys of ArmatureB to the buffer (ctrl+C) ; merging ArmatureB into ArmatureA ; create some new (random) keys for the bones from armatureB, select those bones ; paste from the buffer (Ctrl+V). AND if armatureB was previously parented to a bone of armatureA, you need to re-parent it inside the new armature. Not exactly straightforward.

Comment: it's not even pasting now, and when it does, it delets the old mesh and it still doesn't move. Ive gotta be doing something wrong..
could I add you on discord or something and show you what Im doing?
Thanks

Comment: I can't right now, but you can add me on discord (tag in my profile)